# "No rule to make target" compiling c++ module for Apache Ignite

Tags: build, ignite

When compiling the c++ module from sources I am getting the following error, which seems to arise because the file "ignite/impl/interop/interop_target.h" is missing.  Any suggestions where I should go from here?

```
Making all in include
make[3]: Entering directory `/work/apache-ignite-1.7.0-src/modules/platforms/cpp/core/include'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/work/apache-ignite-1.7.0-src/modules/platforms/cpp/core/include'
make[3]: *** No rule to make target `ignite/impl/interop/interop_target.h', needed by `all-am'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/work/apache-ignite-1.7.0-src/modules/platforms/cpp/core'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/work/apache-ignite-1.7.0-src/modules/platforms/cpp'
make: *** [all] Error 2
The command '/bin/sh -c cd /work/apache-ignite-1.7.0-src/modules/platforms/cpp  && libtoolize && aclocal && autoheader  && automake --add-missing && autoreconf  && ./configure  && make -j4' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Where the build process I am following, leading up to the error, is

```
cd /work
curl -L -O https://archive.apache.org/dist/ignite/1.7.0/apache-ignite-1.7.0-src.zip
unzip -q apache-ignite-1.7.0-src.zip

cd apache-ignite-1.7.0-src
mvn clean package -DskipTests

cd modules/platforms/cpp
libtoolize && aclocal && autoheader && automake --add-missing && autoreconf
./configure
make -j4
```

Incidentally I am getting the same error if I repeat the build process on apache-ignite-1.8.0-src.zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/when-I-build-ignite-C-it-report-that-the-quot-ignite-im-pl-inter-op-interop-target-h-quot-is-not-exi-td8758.html) with the sources releases. As a solution, you can use sources from [project repository](https://github.com/apache/ignite/releases/tag/1.7.0).

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing. Thanks for confirming.